# Многоуровневое меню, окрашивание пунктов меню

Tags: html, css, меню

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Нужно окрашивать пункт меню, из которого выпадает новый список меню с пунктами. Это работает с пунктами главного меню, но с остальными списками нет. Думаю, что дело в `position` для списков, но не знаю как это поправить. Пробовал следующий список накладывать на предыдущий, результат удручающий.

```css
.topmenu {
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu>li {
  display: flex;
  text-align: start;
  width: 30%;
  background: white;
}

.topmenu>li>a {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 60%;
  transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu>li {
  display: flex;
  text-align: start;
  width: 30%;
}

.submenu>li>a {
  background: white;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 30px;
}

.submenu-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 30%;
  transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu-2>li {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.submenu-2>li>a {
  background: white;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 30px;
}

.topmenu li:hover>.submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 686px;
  background: none;
}

.submenu li:hover>.submenu-2 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 686px;
  background: none;
}

.topmenu>li:hover {
  background: rgb(106, 106, 214);
  /* opacity: .2; */
}

.submenu>li :hover {
  background: rgb(189, 189, 121);
}

.submenu-2>li :hover {
  background: rgb(204, 118, 118);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="topmenu">

      <!-- Внешнее меню -->
      <li>
        <a href="">Клапаны</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <!-- 1й уровень Подменю -->
          <li>
            <a href="">Обратные клапаны</a>
            <!-- 2й уровень Подменю -->
            <ul class="submenu-2">
              <!-- 3й уровень Подменю -->
              <li><a href="">Инструментальные</a></li>
              <li><a href="">На большое ДУ</a></li>
              <li><a href="">До 7000 бар</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Криогенные</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!--  -->
        </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```